# Mac App Store like Button Changing with Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, switch-statement

Okay so what I would like to do is make a page that looks exactly like the app store interface inside the Mac App Store. I want a page that when you click on a button, (like the one to purchase an app in the app store) it changes to a different button, and then when you click the second button, it downloads a file, and switches the button back to the first one.

Make sense? If i could get a way to do this, that would be awesome as I don't have much Javascript experience.

Comment: This is a good question. I don't understand why was it down voted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok not a UX guy but just putting my idea to help..

```
<div id="first button"></div>  //Shows on page.
<div id="second button"><Link to actual download link></div>  // hidden by default
```

On click of "first button".. hide first and show "Second button" on same place.Clicking on 2nd will download the file and show the first button. You can do div hide and show using JS. Thats it. Should work.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=div+hide+and+show+javascript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-beta#hl=en&client=firefox-beta&hs=hVl&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=hide+and+show+Div&oq=hide+and+show+Div&gs_l=serp.3..0l4.12188.16651.0.16823.19.15.1.3.3.0.495.2634.0j6j3j0j2.11.0...0.0...1c.GYjXiGWU1Z0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=7fe54e54ee113ed6&biw=1280&bih=666   The first link should help you